# How do I register custom filter in Google App Engine template system?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

According to Django documentation I've registered my filter:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
# ...
register = template.create_template_register()
@register.filter(name='wld')
def wld(result):
    if result == 1 : return "win"
    if result == 0 : return "loss"
    if result == 0.5 : return "draw"
    return "unknown"
self.response.out.write(template.render("player.html", template_values))
```

somewhere in the template I have code:
`{{result|wld}}`

and when I try to render my template, I get the error: `TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'wld'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have created your custom tag library, you need to register it with the Django template engine:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
template.register_template_library('path.to.lib')
```

Note that the call `template.register_template_library` is a wrapper that is provided as part of the AppEngine SDK. Once you have put this in your `main.py`, the new tags or filters should be available in all of your templates without any further work. No need to use the `{% load %}` tag.

An important note: the functioning of `register_template_library` will vary depending on which version of Django you are using in your AppEngine application. If you are using 0.96, the parameter will be the path to the custom tags library file. If you are using Django 1.2, it will by a python module path to the custom tag library. I posted instructions for making this work [in a post on my blog](http://blog.adamcrossland.net/post/show/fixing-custom-tags-with-django-12).

Comment: Thank you! Once I created directory `tags` putting there empty `__init__.py` and `mytags.py`, containing filter registration and called `template.register_template_library('tags.mytags')` from main.py, everything worked fine!

Comment: Excellent. Very glad to hear it.

Comment: Not needing to use the `{% load %}` tag was the key to an hour of mucking around for me!

Comment: A +1 for the important note part!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `{% load the_name_of_that_module %}` block in every template you plan to use this filter.

Comment: Obviously I'm missing something, I have only main.py script and player.html template. The code above is executed in main.py. How `load` tag should look like?

Comment: GAE uses Django templating system by default and thus follows the [same rules](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/). Basically `load` tag is a built-in tag, but you need to put your custom filters/tags in a particular place in your project package. I strongly recommend reading that piece of documentation, since it explains thoroughly the topic.