# Django TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'truncatechars'

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates, webapp2

`Getting TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'truncatechars'` in app engine. I'm using latest django library.  As per ["Third-party Libraries in Python 2.7 on appengine"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) django latest version is 1.4 and `truncatechars` is included in the same version ([django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)).

index.py

```
import webapp2
import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template    

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        title = " Python, an interactive, object-oriented, extensible programming language."
        template_values = {
            'title': title,
        }
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
{{title|truncatechars:9}} // Error returns

{{title|slice:"9"}}{% if title|length > 9 %}...{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

In app.yaml

```
 libraries:
    - name: django
      version: latest
```

I have tried with library `version: "1.4"` and have the same issue.

Error:

```
File "/home/user/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1595, in handle_exception
    return handler(request, response, e)
  File "/home/user/dimensionfinder/urls.py", line 43, in handle_500
    response.write(template.render(path, template_values))
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 89, in render
    t = _load_internal_django(template_path, debug)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 163, in _load_internal_django
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 160, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(template, origin, template_name)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 168, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 186, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 693, in do_for
    nodelist_loop = parser.parse(('empty', 'endfor',))
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 262, in parse
    filter_expression = self.compile_filter(token.contents)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 356, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 538, in __init__
    filter_func = parser.find_filter(filter_name)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 362, in find_filter
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("Invalid filter: '%s'" % filter_name)
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'truncatechars'
```

Comment: how about `version: "1.4"` (with double quote)?

Comment: if it doesn't work, you can always fallback to use `|slice:":9"`

Comment: You should show the code you're using to render the template. You're not actually using Django, you're using webapp, so you must be doing something to import it and use the template rendering component, and the issue must be there.

Comment: @Hieu Nguyen: With 'version: "1.4"' Same error. Currently using slice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091596/how-do-i-register-custom-filter-in-google-app-engine-template-system

Answer (score 0):

You should either use the Django templating stuff directly (without the webapp wrapper).

[How do I use Django templates without the rest of Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98135/how-do-i-use-django-templates-without-the-rest-of-django)

Or use the recommended Jinja2 template engine.

[Using Jinja2 templates with Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates)